# Raspberry Pi 3 clock won't sync after reboot

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, time, gentoo, ntp

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running Gentoo and the clock doesn't sync with NTP after a reboot. Once the system comes up again it restores the last recorded time from swclock. I have to start the ntp-client service manually to get the clock synced. The configuration seems right as swclock is on boot level and ntp-client is on default level.

Comment: I have /etc/conf.d/ntpd and the current option is -g, yet I'm not using the daemon only the client. Referencing the ntpd options (http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpd) -s is used to define a directory.

Comment: Is the Pi directly connected to the network or on wireless? I had this issue as well when on wireless. Cleared up when hardlined.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this when using DNSSec. If the time is too far off then DNSSec won't resolve DNS names, so the NTP daemon cannot get IP addresses to synchronise against.

One solution might be to ensure that at least one of your NTP servers or peers is an IP address or locally resolvable name.

I run `named` on one of my Pi's, and I have added this snippet to the end of `/etc/default/bind9`. Two of my `server` entries are explicit IP addresses, and the others eventually get resolved when DNS starts working.

```
# Get an approximation to current time so that DNS will work, so that
# NTP can resolve its server/peer names
#
test -x /usr/sbin/ntpdate -a -s /etc/ntp.conf &&
    awk '/^server|^peer/ {print $2}' /etc/ntp.conf | xargs -r ntpdate || :
```